# How does !! work in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-history

Very useful when you forget a sudo at the beginning of your command, `!!` acts like an alias of the previous command. Example :

```
$ mv /very/long/path/for/a/protected/sensible/file/caution.h .
(...) Permission denined
$ sudo !!
sudo mv /very/long/path/for(...) .
[sudo] password :
```

- How do we call that double `!!` trick ?
  Researches over internet are difficult because of that token.
- How does it work ? I suspect a link with the history command.
- Where it is defined ? Can I define some other myself ?

EDIT : Some interesting event designators

#### `!!:*`

It refers to the arguments of the previous command.
Use case :

```
cat /a/file/to/read/with/long/path
nano !!:*
```

#### `:p`

Just print the command without executing it, you have to put it at the end of the event designator.

```
$ !-5:p
sudo rm /etc/fstab -f
```

[More here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/bash-history-expansion/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20TheGeekStuff%20(The%20Geek%20Stuff)).

Comment: Read `man history`

Comment: It's a special case of history expansion, in which the shell attempts to expand a word starting with `!` to a matching command in the current shell's history list. `!!` is a special case, equivalent to `!-1`, where a negative number `n` following `!` refers to the nth previous command.

Comment: @Costas, more usefully, read `LESS='+/^HISTORY EXPANSION' man bash`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`!!` is listed in the `bash` manual under the heading "Event Designators":

```
   An event designator is a reference to a command line  entry  in  the
   history list.  Unless the reference is absolute, events are relative
   to the current position in the history list.

   !      Start a history  substitution,  except  when  followed  by  a
          blank,  newline,  carriage  return,  = or ( (when the extglob
          shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin).
   !n     Refer to command line n.
   !-n    Refer to the current command minus n.
   !!     Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for  `!-1'.
   !string
          Refer  to the most recent command preceding the current posi-
          tion in the history list starting with string.
   !?string[?]
          Refer to the most recent command preceding the current  posi-
          tion  in  the history list containing string.  The trailing ?
          may be omitted if string is followed immediately  by  a  new-
          line.
   ^string1^string2^
          Quick  substitution.   Repeat the previous command, replacing
          string1       with       string2.        Equivalent        to
          ``!!:s/string1/string2/'' (see Modifiers below).
   !#     The entire command line typed so far.
```

So `!!` will be replaced with the previous command.

Note that the shell history will not contain the literal `!!` but instead the actual command that was executed:

```
$ ls
[some output]

$ !! .
[same output]

$ history 3
  645  2016-08-25 17:40:55 ls
  646  2016-08-25 17:40:57 ls .
  647  2016-08-25 17:41:00 history 3
```